# iReport - Print when expression to control whole layout or not

Tags: jasper-reports

I am in an urgent need of having the print layout thing based on the one fied condition.  Let us say I have a shipment label layout with 50 fields in it and which is working.  But before I print that, I have a condition saying that if Number of Packages is 0 do not print at all. Just print an error message saying that no packages and no labels.  Which means when that particular actions is taken, if the number of packages is 0 then it should print only a message and not the total print layout with 50 fields.

Anythoughts,  I went through lot of documentation.  I found only print when expression is used at field level.  if that's case do I need add that check for all the 50 fileds :).

Please clarify or suggest.

Regards,
~Madhu

Answer (score 0):

did u meant u dont want to display the report page if there is no data? If that case, u just have to go to report propeties, then at the "more" band, you change "when No Data Type" to No Page.

Answer (score 0):

- The program might query with `SELECT COUNT(*)` before running the report. If the count is zero, then the program shows the message; otherwise, it will shows the report.
- Get the list of pages from `JasperPrint`. The list size is the number of pages.

  ```
  JasperPrint print;
  print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(filename, map, connection);
  List list = print.getPages();
  System.out.println(list.size());
  ```